# how to create a function such that it create dataframes by iterating over a master dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, data-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe. And I want to create seperate dataframe for every state, some states are multiple times

[image]

I know one way:

```
GOA_filter = df['STATE/UT']=='GOA'
GOA_df = df[GOA_filter]
```

this way I create dataframe of GOA,
I don't want to do it manually for every state.
So Is it possible to create a function such that it create dataframes by the name "state_df" ???
Like: GOA_df, HARYANA_df etc...

Comment: So what's the expected output in the example you have provided?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco, the expecatation is dataframes should get created for every state.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, the idea is to create a dictionary of dataframes that you can call.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "State": ["GOA", "AP", "UP", "AB", "Punjab"],
        "vals": np.random.randint(0, 500, size=5),
    }
)
dfs = {}
for state, frame in df.groupby('State'):
   dfs[state] = frame


print(dfs['GOA'])
  State  vals
0   GOA   227
```

Comment: this is the best way IMO +1

Comment: @anky_91 thanks I've never really found the need to do this in my own code tho, can never think of a use case for it.

Comment: sometimes it may be required if you want to save dataframes somewhere with a reference

Comment: @anky_91 even so I think it can be simplified just by using pathlib and calling the groupby on it's own, few months ago I had to export a small dB (i think it was 50 gb) and used pathlib and pandas to a similair thing, it wasn't more than 15 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try with some like this :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
STATE/UT
A
A
B
C
C
D
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',')
for x, y in df.groupby('STATE/UT'):
    print('df')
    print(y)
```

Result :

```
df
  STATE/UT
0        A
1        A
df
  STATE/UT
2        B
df
  STATE/UT
3        C
4        C
df
  STATE/UT
5        D
```